# Circle Not Generating For All Value In csv File In ScatterPlot d3js

Tags: csv, d3.js

I'm Learning To Create ScatterPlot With Data From External csv  File Below Is How My File Looks Like

```html
x,y
5,20 
480,90
250,50 
100,33 
330,95
410,12
475,44
25,67
85,21
220,88
10,10
```

My JS & CSS Codes Are

```js
//Call csv File 
d3.csv("data.csv", function (error, data) {
    //Check For Error
    if (error) console.log("Error");
    /*
    Check For Data
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        console.log("X Is "+ d.x);
        console.log("Y Is "+ d.y);
    });
    */
    //Create Margin
    var margin = { top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 60, left: 60 },
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    /*
   define scale then followed by axis
   */
    // define x and y scales
    // define x and y scales
    xMax = d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.x;
    });
    yMax = d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.y;
    });
    console.log(xMax);
    var xScale = d3.scale.linear().
        domain([0, xMax]).
        range([0, width]);
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear().
        domain([0, yMax]).
        range([height, 0]);
    // define x axis and y axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().
        scale(xScale).
        orient("bottom");
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().
        scale(yScale).
        orient("left");
    /*
    Create Tooltip
    */
    var toolTip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function (d) {
          
          return ('X = '+ d.x +" Y = "+d.y);
      });
    /*
   create svg element then append height and width and g which act as a container
   */
    var svg = d3.select("body").
      append("svg").
      attr({
          "width": width + margin.right + margin.left,
          "height": height + margin.top + margin.bottom
      }).
    append("g").
      attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")");

    //call toolTip
    svg.call(toolTip);
    // Draw xAxis
    svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(xAxis);
    //Draw yAxis
    svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis")
     .call(yAxis);
    /*
 create bar or bind data
 */
    //bind data
    svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
   //enter data
    .enter().
        append("circle")
   //update data
      .attr("class", "circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return xScale(d.x); })
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return yScale(d.y); })
      .attr("r", 8)
      .on('mouseover', toolTip.show)
      .on('mouseout', toolTip.hide);
});
```

```css
svg {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  background-color:antiquewhite;
}
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered ;
}
.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

Output I Am Getting Is Like

[image]

Which Shows Only Four Circle But I Had More Then 10 Input In My csv File.Can Any One Point Me What Is Wrong

Comment: seems to be working for me : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/871j8dsp/, i changed the csv to JSON via : http://www.csvjson.com/csv2json, and attached it to a variable called data and it works fine which means it something to do with parsing your csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things:

```
  xMax = d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.x;
    });
    yMax = d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.x;
    });
```

1) csv parsing returns strings by default. It will return the max value as the alphabetically maximum value for x, which is "85" in your data. Look at your screenshot and see where your x axis ends...

2) you're using d.x to calculate the max y value too

Should be:

```
  xMax = d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return +d.x;
    });
    yMax = d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return +d.y;
    });
```

Comment: thank for for correcting me i noticed xMax value is "85" . is there any Fix for this  So That It Will So Highest Value Or I Need To Use json file and i  Corrected dx in "yMax" to dy

Comment: you just put '+' in front to turn it into a number, like in my answer above, or use the json route suggested in the comment